# Can't get google to display breadcrumb in search results

Tags: html, breadcrumbs, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I'm trying to get Google to show my breadcrumb in search results by using schema.org's breadcrumb micro data.  When I use Google's structured data testing tool, the breadcrumb doesn't show in the search results sample and the following message appears: "The excerpt from the page will show up here. The reason we can't show text from your webpage is because the text depends on the query the user types."

I don't understand that because the URL I'm using doesn't contain a query string (it's http://www.fastfoodnutrition.org/6_r-taco-bell/8511_i-sausage-flatbread-melt-nutrition-facts.html)

Here's my code:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/breadcrumb">
<li><a itemprop="url" href="/6_r-taco-bell/nutrition-facts.html" title="/6_r-taco-bell/nutrition-facts.html"><span itemprop="title">Taco Bell</span></a></li>
<li><a itemprop="url" href="/6_r-taco-bell/269_c-breakfast-nutrition-facts.html" title="/6_r-taco-bell/269_c-breakfast-nutrition-facts.html"><span itemprop="title">Breakfast</span></a></li>
<li>Sausage Flatbread Melt Nutrition Facts</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Side note: It has to be `itemtype="http://schema.org/Breadcrumb"` (capital *B*) instead of `itemtype="http://schema.org/breadcrumb"`.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't recognize them yet, you should use http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb instead and it will be recognized by the RichSnippets tool as [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en) Google post suggest. So your code would be:

```
<ol>
  <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a itemprop="url" href="/6_r-taco-bell/nutrition-facts.html" title="/6_r-taco-bell/nutrition-facts.html">
             <span itemprop="title">Taco Bell</span>
        </a>
  </li>
  <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a itemprop="url" href="/6_r-taco-bell/269_c-breakfast-nutrition-facts.html" title="/6_r-taco-bell/269_c-breakfast-nutrition-facts.html">
             <span itemprop="title">Breakfast</span>
        </a>
  </li>
  <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <span itemprop="title">Sausage Flatbread Melt Nutrition Facts</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```